# Python recursive "and" functionality?

Tags: python, recursion, operators

I was trying to deal with the issue of generating nested tuples vs. flat lists.  I wanted to get the max number of iterations performed by this function (n_iter).  I seemingly resolved the issue with leveraging an "and" operator vs. a "," between my call backs to the initial functions.  Additionally, this is functioning remarkably faster. Anyone know why this logic worked?  Does it have to do with an evaluation where the "and" appears? Full disclosure this was for a  homework assignment, but I seem to have answered it.

```
#n_iter should start as zero
def break_it_down(n, n_iter):
    if n > 2:
        division, subtraction = n/2.0, n-1.0
        n_iter +=1
        return break_it_down(division,n_iter) and break_it_down(subtraction, n_iter)
    return n_iter
```

Comment: your question is not clear! what you are trying to do? what ever value i pass to your function, it returns that value minus 2. what you want to achieve with your code. please briefly explain your and it's output.

Comment: What do you think that `and` is doing? It looks wrong.

Comment: So my code is intended to determine the maximum number of plays available to a player in a game where two players can either choose to divide a number by 2 or subtract 1.  The and is returning the "max" value from the nested tuples.

Comment: "The and is returning the "max" value from the nested tuples." - no it's not. (Also, you have no nested tuples.)

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry- it "appeared" to be returning the max value.  It was a nested tuple when I had a "," that was in place of the and now presently there.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `and` is "short-cirtuiting". In

```
<expr-1> and <expr-2>
```

the expression `<expr-2>` will not be evaluated if the result of `<expr-1>` is  "falsy" (i.e. it is considered `False` in a logical context).

In your case for example calling with `n=8` division is

```
n=4 → n=2 → n=1 -> n=0
```

(in Python 2, 1/2 is 0 when the input are integer numbers)

and instead subtraction

```
n=8 → n=7 → n=6 → n=5 → n=4 → n=3 → n=2 → n=1 → n=0
```

the value `n=0` is "falsy" but can be reached much faster with division than with subtraction. This means that if you first check with division and only then with subtraction the number of calls will be much smaller:

```
# division first
n=8
n=8/2=4 and n=8-1=7
n=4/2=2 and n=4-1=3
n=2/2=1 and n=2-1=1
n=1/2=0 and n=1-1=0 (stop)

# subtraction first
n=8
n=8-1=7 and n=8/2=4
n=7-1=6 and n=7/2=3
n=6-1=5 and n=6/2=3
n=5-1=4 and n=5/2=2
n=4-1=3 and n=4/2=2
n=3-1=2 and n=3/2=1
n=2-1=1 and n=2/2=1
n=1-1=0 and n=1/2=0 (stop)
```

with bigger inputs the difference is even larger (for example 256 requires 256 subtractions to get to 0 but only 8 divisions).

Comment: Great! Really appreciate the explanation! Makes total sense.  Appreciate taking the time to teach me!